# Page not found - Wamp green, phpmyadmin working

Tags: 404-error

I was working using a Wamp server installed on my computer and everything was working fine for my Wordpress site. But when I installed a plugin, the entire WP site is gone as it displays "Oops! That page can’t be found."

Status:
My Wamp is green, and I can access phpmyadmin and see my database. But I can't establish a connection via localhost to the front or backend of Wordpress.
I've also checked my Apache error log and there isn't anything using port 80.

I've tried to use

```
"define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);"
```

on 'wp-config' but no luck. I m pretty new to this Wordpress development, so please do guide me through how to fix this. Thank you

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have two different Wordpress websites, both of them is working prior to this issue. But after this one Wordpress site went 404, the other Wordpress site suddenly can't read its css files, as the text are still the same.

Answer (score 2):

My first step would be to turn on `WP_DEBUG` in your wp-config.php file.

Edit wp-config.php and add the following lines:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Then visit your site's admin (example.com/wp-admin) and see if an error appears. More than likely the plugin you just added broke the site, so you can go into your local filesystem (where WordPress is stored) and deactivate the plugin.

1. Go to your WordPress install (via your File Explorer).
2. Open wp-content/plugins/
3. Find the plugin you just activated when things broke. Rename that folder to something else (example: `bad-plugin` renamed to `bad-plugin-1`)

Now try to visit your site. By renaming the plugin it forces WordPress to deactivate it and it may bring the site back.

Here are some additional debugging tips for WordPress as well:

- https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
- https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/wordpress2/debugging-wordpress
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLNIARUfSj8
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nj2ziU6_0F8

### Updated Answer

The comments of this answer revealed that the main issue was with the file path leading to the WordPress installation. The file path was `localhost/wordpress%20G`, but the WordPress site_url parameter was set to `localhost/wordpress/`.

By visiting the url `localhost/wordpress%20G`, WordPress was rendered but was firing a 404 error. By renaming the folder to `wordpress` (removing the space and letter G) the WordPress installation began to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I've tried renaming the plugin, but it does not work. I have also tried setting WP_DEBUG and going to the admin, but all I got was "The requested URL /wordpress/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) PHP/7.2.18 Server at localhost Port 80"

Comment: Based on a WordPress.org thread (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-17/) I would recommend trying to visit "your-wamp-website-url.com/readme.html" and see if that renders. If it does, then there is a PHP specific problem. If it still shows the same error, then there is a larger issue with WAMP.

Comment: Ahh thanks Tom! I can reach my site's readme.html so this means it could be a php error

Comment: Great! Since we think it's a PHP error, head over to your WordPress install and open up index.php. Comment out everything in the file and then type something in there to show that PHP is running, like this: `<?php print_r('hello from php'); die();'. If you visit your site and see the message "hello from php", then your server is running fine and WordPress is the issue. If you see no message and an error, then your server is the issue.

Comment: Ahh I tried printing "hello from php" in the index file, and my site does echo "hello from php". This must be an Wordpress issue

Comment: Great news, you're debugging! Now remove your changes from index.php and uncomment the WordPress-code inside there. Then, open wp-config.php and search the file for "WP_DEBUG". Make sure that it is set to "true" (like this: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`. Then, under the defined wp_debug, put the following: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` and try to access your site. You should see errors when visiting the homepage or wp-admin (try both).

Comment: hmm strange, I tried enabling "WP_DEBUG" and enable error reporting in the wp-config file, and when I remove the comment (revert) my index file; I didn't received any error message, just an 404 page not found.

Comment: Can you screenshot the 404 page, post it and link it here? I'd like to see if it's an apache 404 (your server generates it) or WordPress-generated 404.

Comment: here I uploaded the image on my Google Drive, it should be view-able for all: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AwEWysB9XfS2EPvkI64L6f1cQJxKVVZI

Comment: Got it. The 404 looks like it's coming from WordPress (I am seeing your blogs title and subtitle "Just another WordPress site") but the CSS doesn't seem to be loading. Can you right-click and select the "View Source" option and screenshot that?

Comment: so here is my source file; https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mPgCE_bDU9Fm_2MF7M-ZQEgkqK9XTjuG/view | and here is my theme folder ; https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MdG8wkn2Fl3BybegDuVn2CxBrWYjm-Q3/view

Comment: Thanks for posting those screenshots. I think I found the issue. If you look at your first screenshot, the URL you are visiting is localhost/wordpress%20G (wordpress space G). That makes sense, because in your second screenshot we can see that the folder path is wamp64/www/wordpress G/. However, looking at your source code, the URL WordPress is set to is "localhost/wordpress/" (no space-G). What I recommend is renaming the folder that WordPress lives in from "wordpress G" to just wordpress. That should make the site work correctly. Please let me know if this works and I can update the answer.

Comment: Alright! It seems WP can read the file now, thanks so much Tom. Btw I m facing something weird in the backend admin page, it does not have any styling to it. Here is the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aX2wmRhlkvbtSyLfa0gmzbiWVGBfJTVW

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I'll update my answer with the actual solution. In regards to the admin issue, can you take two screenshots? The first of the source code (like before) and the second by opening Chome developer tools and finding the console tab. You can read more about devtools here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Comment: Strange, it gave me a 404 error again eventhough I didn't work on it. Here is the inspect srouce: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wHtJELWXj9DhzUaVZbuPRAZArH6SodM7 and here is my inspect source: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1np3WzGUtHDhr8C164XZqJWr-dBAf97hk

Comment: From what I'm seeing, your WordPress install may have an issue with the siteurl. Now I see WordPress thinking it lives at `localhost/wordpress%G/` but you are visiting the site at `localhost/wordpress/`. https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdhilftfuahtpg8/inspect%20source.png?dl=0 You should check PHPMyAdmin and look at your wp_options table for `site_url` and `home_url`.